# How to retrieve Posts in WordPress into a custom HTML Table?

Tags: php, pagination, wordpress-theming, wordpress

***My question is How can I create two rows with 2 columns `<td>`  in a Dynamic way, receiving posts from the `query_post()`!***

I spent sometime using the `query_post()` in WordPress to create this  :

[image]

I made a drastic mistake and this is the snippet:

http://pastebin.com/cp6RSTQQ

this gives me the recent posts of a ***category*** called ***watch*** using the `offset` in the `query_post()`
in this way:

```
<?php
            $args = array( 'posts_per_page' => 1, 'order'=> 'DESC','category' => 'watch', 'orderby' => 'post_date','offset' => 0 );
            $postslist = get_posts( $args );
            foreach ($postslist as $post) :  setup_postdata($post); ?> 

            <td class="leftBoxes">

            <div class="imgMargin"> <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?> </div>
           <br>

            <div class="boxScrollsBlogsView">
            <h2><?php the_title(); ?> </h2>
            <P> 
            <?php the_excerpt(); ?> 
            </P>
            <h3><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"> ReadMore</a></h3>
            </div>

            </td>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
```

After I wanted to go forward, I realized that I can't do ***pagination***  in the way I wrote th code!

I have looked at this [QUESTION](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/grid-view-on-page-of-postphp) on wordpress website, but I can't understand how he is doing it honestly!

Comment: You might want to consider using CSS grids instead of a table. It'll make this easier, and allow you to build something that you can scale down to a mobile screen if you wanted to.

Comment: @ChrisFerdinandi, thanks I usually use Bootstrap, but this time the design is very complex, and this is somehow my only solution.

Comment: So what you're looking to do is get posts, just from a specific category, and split all of those into two columns, with pagination? I'm sure there's a way - just want to clarify first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just deleted the the right box and I changed the code to look like this

```
<?php
        $args = array( 'posts_per_page' => 4, 'order'=> 'DESC','category' => 'watch', 'orderby' => 'post_date','offset' => 0 );
        $postslist = get_posts( $args );
        foreach ($postslist as $post) :  setup_postdata($post); ?> 

        <td class="leftBoxes">

        <div class="imgMargin"> <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?> </div>
       <br>

        <div class="boxScrollsBlogsView">
        <h2><?php the_title(); ?> </h2>
        <P> 
        <?php the_excerpt(); ?> 
        </P>
        <h3><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"> ReadMore</a></h3>
        </div>

        </td>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
```

and it creates one TD after another eventually it goes to the new line for making rows